# dynamically applying image src is not working in FF and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Try the follwing code in w3schools in FF, IE and chrome. Observe the behavior.
In chrome the image is reloading. But in IE and FF it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function changeSrc()
    {
        document.getElementById("myImage").src="some captcha url";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="myImage" src="compman.gif" width="107" height="98">
<br><br>
<a href="#" onclick="changeSrc();">reload</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Sravanthi.

Comment: dont try that, its bad practice, instead make a div above it and remove/recreate the image using the parent div.

Comment: I would suggest you to try jquery

Comment: I tried Jquery as well. But it didn't work.

Comment: The code should work fine, which version of IE and FF you are checking with?

Comment: here(http://jsfiddle.net/rahulr/ZwAHQ/) is jsfiddle of your code, and its working fine in IE8..

Answer (score 0):

Try Close the final Quote and add the `;`, before the last `}`

```
function changeSrc()  
{
    document.getElementById("myImage").src="some captcha url";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need. Don't forget to include the latest version of jQuery in your script:

```
$(function () {
//REFRESH CAPTHCA IMAGE
$("div#refresh").on("click", function()
    {
        var newSrc= "some captcha url";
        $("#myImage").attr("src",newSrc);
    });

  });



    <img id="myImage" src="compman.gif" width="107" height="98">


    <div id="refresh"> Refresh </div>
```

Comment: I used src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"